# Memory leak in cgal?

Tags: memory-leaks, cgal

I have a simple cgal program where I do a lot of unions of 2d polygons with Polygon_set_2 and an Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.
(I do not use multithreading)
To benchmark I repeat this a number of times using a for loop.
Inside the loop I declare the Set and add polygons to the set. Therefor the set is only in the loop and I should start with a new set each iteration.
The first iteration is quite fast and looks good. But all other iterations are far slower and I can also see that the needed memory increases with the number of iterations. It looks like the objects in the loop are destroyed at the end of the iteration but the memory is not freed.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_set_2.h>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K>                                Polygon_2;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_set_2<K>                            Polygon_set_2;
typedef CGAL::Point_2<K>                                  Point;
typedef std::chrono::system_clock                         system_clock;

std::vector<std::array<double[2],3>> generate_points(int maxId);

  int main()
{
  const int Runs = 10; //repeats for benchmarking
  const int maxId = 50; //50 x 50 x 2 polygons
  auto polygon_points = generate_points(maxId); //generates the coordinate points of the polygons
  std::cout << "Number of planned polygons " << polygon_points.size() << "\n";

  std::array<Polygon_2, 50 * 50 * 2> all_polygons; //to pregenerate polygons
  for(size_t i = 0; i < polygon_points.size(); ++i){
    for(auto pnt:polygon_points[i]){
      all_polygons[i].push_back(Point(pnt[0], pnt[1]));
    }
  }
  
  //Benchmarking part. Here is the part where I suspect an error
  for(int run = 0; run < Runs; ++run){
    Polygon_set_2 Set;
    std::chrono::time_point<system_clock> start = system_clock::now();
    for(auto &ply:all_polygons){
      Set.join(ply);
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<system_clock> end = system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << " s to join " << polygon_points.size() << " polygons\n";
  }
  return 0;
}

//function to generate all coodinate points of the polynoms I later want to join
std::vector<std::array<double[2],3>> generate_points(int maxId){
  std::vector<std::array<double[2],3>> polygons;
  polygons.reserve(2 * maxId * maxId);
  double dx{1.0/maxId};
  double dy{dx};
  for(int Idx = 0; Idx < maxId; ++Idx){
    for(int Idy = 0; Idy < maxId; ++Idy){
        polygons.emplace_back(std::array<double[2],3>{{{Idx * dx, Idy * dy},{(Idx + 1) * dx, Idy * dy},{Idx * dx, (Idy + 1) * dy}}});
        polygons.emplace_back(std::array<double[2],3>{{{(Idx + 1) * dx, Idy * dy},{(Idx + 1) * dx, (Idy + 1) * dy},{Idx * dx, (Idy + 1) * dy}}});
    }
  }
  return polygons;
}
```

Is there a known memory leak in cgal?
Or is there a common mistake I probably do?

Comment: You should submit an issue [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues) with a minimal example showing the problem so that we can try reproduce it. If you observe a memory leak it is a bug and it should be fixed.

Comment: I added a simplified version of the code to my post. Before opening an issue I want to make sure that it is not a trivial error I do.

Comment: What cgal version?

Comment: (I think this has already been fixed, so it would be good if you could try with the latest version)

Comment: Thank you Marc, I used the version provided by apt, which is 5.4-1.
Now I used 5.5-1. and it works. You are right, there it is fixed. Thanks a lot :)